# Android ListView Adapter returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview

The app crashes when trying to populate images in to a holder's ImageView or when I try to set an onclick listener to the holder imageview. It actually crashes if I try to do **anything** related to the holder's imageview.

> The Image URL is not null, I checked
>
> The ImageView exists, I checked

**Adapter code (Important bits of it):**

```
 public class FeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    
    static private Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    ArrayList<ActivityTable> actList = new ArrayList<ActivityTable>();
    Holder holder;
    
    public FeedAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ActivityTable> actList) {
            activity = a;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.actList = actList;
    }
    
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
            View vi = convertView;
            final ActivityTable act = actList.get(position);
    
            if (vi == null) {
                  vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_picture, parent, false);
                  holder = new Holder();
                  holder.media = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.postphoto);
                  //can't set an image to it either. it crashes.
            }
            else {
                  holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
            }
            
            //This is where it crashes
            holder.media.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        
                              //other on Click related Code
                        
                        }
            });
       return vi;
    }

    public static class Holder {
            ImageView media;
    }
}
```

Why does the Holder's ImageView crash? I tried adding a TextView, ImageButton, etc and all of them work properly. Just this specific imageview crashes. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT: Crash Log**

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.metalproject.metalprojectmobile, PID: 5737
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at Adapter.FeedAdapter.getView(FeedAdapter.java:456)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2689)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:661)
```

**The above line: 456 points to -> holder.media.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {**

Comment: Sure. Hold on @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: If possible please also share `feed_single_picture.xml` file code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should modify your code as below :

```
if (vi == null) {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_picture, parent, false);
    holder = new Holder();
    holder.media = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.postphoto);
}
```

and also remove them from outer code of if else

Comment: Sorry I checked and my bad, the code was in the same format you gave me. Edited the question

Comment: have you added  vi.setTag(holder ); in if block?

Comment: can you post your whole code of adapter with feed_single_picture.xml file ?

Comment: @Earthling you should bind your view and layout in holder class, not in *getView* method.

Comment: I didn;t know that :O @adnbsr So all that findViewBy... part comes in the holder class?

Answer (score 0):

Fix will be like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ActivityTable act = actList.get(position);

    if (vi == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_single_picture, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder = (Holder) vi.getTag();
    }

    holder.media.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       }
    });
    return vi;
}

static class Holder {

    private ImageView media;

    Holder(View view){
        this.media = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.postphoto);
    }

}
```

Comment: What about setting a URL and all that code? Where should I put those?

Comment: After if/else block, you will have all defined views and you can set there. Note: use Picasso or Glide